# How do I create custom distance between tick marks in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: Example]

Anyone knows how can I do custom tick marks similar to the left y axis in this picture?

I have been able to create the tick marks using 'breaks' argument. However, the distance between the tick marks are tricky here. For example, the distance between 0 and 1 are double of what between 1 and 2, and the same as the distance between 2 and 5. I don't know how to use trans_new to create specific distance like that. Do anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: In your image there are about 62 pixels between 0 and 1 and about 40 pixels between 1 and 2 - so it is not half. I'd suggest using a signed square root transform, I bet that will at least be close. [Here's a page implementing it](https://andrewpwheeler.com/2015/07/31/custom-square-root-scale-with-negative-values-in-ggplot2-r/).

Comment: Thanks, I tried signed square root transform. It look decently close but the distance between -100 and -200 in that case is way bigger comparing to the picture. I'm also curious if there is anyway to manually specific the distance between each tick marks instead of using a transform function.

Comment: The way to get a non-linear scale is to define a transform, but that transform can be as complicated as you like. You could define a transform piecewise to have whatever characteristics/distances you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like it might be using a `pseudo_log` transformation, which smoothly transitions between a signed log scale for values beyond `sigma` to a linear scale within +/- `sigma`. Adjusting that value will shift how much space is allotted to the region near 0 versus for values farther from it.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = "Brazil", y = c(-100, 7), type = letters[1:2]),
       aes(x, y, color = type)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 0.5),
                     limits = c(-200, 20),
                     breaks = c(-200, -100, -50, -20, -10, -5, (-2):2, 5, 10, 20),
                     minor_breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

---

[image]

```
library(animation)
saveGIF({
  for (i in (1.15^c(0:100,100:0))/1E3) {
    print(ggplot(data.frame(x = "Brazil", y = c(-100, 7), type = letters[1:2]),
           aes(x, y, color = type)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = paste("pseudo_log_trans' sigma set to", formatC(i, format = "fg", digits = 3))) +
      scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = i),
                         limits = c(-200, 20),
                         breaks = c(-200, -100, -50, -20, -10, -5, (-2):2, 5, 10, 20),
                         minor_breaks = NULL)
    )
    
  }
},
interval = 1/20)
```